# Excluding plugin apply for certain subprojects in gradle multi-project build

Tags: gradle, properties, gradle-plugin, multi-project, subproject

How can I exclude certain subprojects in my multi-project gradle build.
I want to exclude a apply plugin call by querying a property of the subproject.

The build.gradle of my parent project looks like this:

```
subprojects {
    if (!ext.has('excludeProject')) {
        apply plugin: 'org.example.DemoPlugin'
    }
}
```

And the build.gradle of some subprobjects contain this:

```
ext {
    excludeProject = true
}
```

This does not work. The plugin is always applied. I also tried different syntax like
if(!project.ext.exclude) or if(!project.hasProperty('exclude')).

What works is: if I put a "gradle.properties" in the subproject and define the property there (excludeProject=true), then it works.

If I query "if(project.name != "subproject")that also works, but I dont want that solution.
Is there a way to get it working by using extension properties in the build.gradle ?

Answer (score 1):

Placing the `excludeProject` in the `buildscript { ext { ... } }` appears to be applying the property too late for the `subprojects { ... }` to detect them.

You can place a line like this in your `subprojects { ... }` to reveal the properties available at that time:

> `println(ppp.ext.getProperties().keySet())`

The project simply isn't evaluated enough yet for these to be populated if you do it this way.  However, if you place `excludeProject = true` into a `gradle.properties` in your sub-module, it does detect it through what I tried (Gradle 8.0.1).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I also think that it is simply not possible that way. I will use the gradle.properties workaround until I find a better solution.